# Implement server and client

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, web-applications

I need to implement a server that downloads a webpage and sends it to a client that saves it as a file.

On the server side I need to process socket.

So I was thinking about making a web service in java (with netbeans) but I don't know how to start the web service (I use osx lion).

How can I start the web service?
Is there another way to solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly consider just using an HTTP-based RESTful client/server, using any of a million server-side frameworks. The server-side option may influence the client side implementation.

For example, you could use something like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), which can also create the client-side library needed to consume your service.

On the server side I'd use something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) to retrieve the websites that will be returned to the client app.

Comment: It seems like its what I'm looking for, is there any tutorial about how to use it?

Comment: @DanielDavila I'd check the [getting started](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e8) guide, or [this shorter one](http://jersey.java.net/use/getting-started.html) to get a feel for it.